# How to make a trigger click with interval on buttons in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, intervals

I have a list with buttons. I want to make an interval trigger on each button in sequence one by one and if it reaches the last interval it starts again.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('button').trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
  <li><button></button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you just need a variable to track which button should be clicked, and then use `eq()` to select the `button` by index:

```js
let index = 0, $buttons = $('button');

setInterval(function() {
  $buttons.eq(index % $buttons.length).trigger('click');
  index++;
}, 1000);

// to test:
$('button').on('click', function(i) {
  console.log(`Button ${this.id} was clicked`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><button id="1"></button></li>
  <li><button id="2"></button></li>
  <li><button id="3"></button></li>
  <li><button id="4"></button></li>
  <li><button id="5"></button></li>
</ul>
```

It's worth noting that triggering `click` events is not necessarily the best method to achieve whatever it is you require. I'd suggest directly calling a function instead.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks. I just needed it to start a dynamic gallery in woocommerce single product page, now its working just I wanted.

Comment: Is it possible to make it if user clicked when interval already started on 3rd button the next trigger will be on 4th button not 1st?

Comment: Yep, you can get the `index()` of the clicked button, then add one to it and set it as the value of `index`

Answer (score 1):

Number of ways to do this. Just continuously loop over them with one setInterval for example (with vanilla):

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
let index = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
  index = index % buttons.length; // set to 0 if over max
  buttons[index].click();
  // do something...
  buttons[index].innerText = buttons[index].innerText != 'clicked' ? 'clicked' : 'click me';
  // ...do something
  index++;
},1000)
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
<button>click me</button>
```